# How should I pass negative values to SendMessage and Perform when they expect a NativeUInt?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

Suppose you have code like this:

```
Result.X := ACustomMemo.Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, -1, 0);
```

The Windows API claims "-1" is a valid value that makes it it return the active line.

However, Delphi has this defined as NaiveUInt and complains if I try to pass -1.

What is the cleanest solution to this? Casting?

Comment: Get used to the fact that more casting is now required, due to Win64 cleanups in the API (NativeUINT). Not only here but in other places where Win32 and Win64 APIs use nativeInt or nativeUint.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Casting the -1 value to WPARAM is the proper way to handle this case.

```
 Result.X := ACustomMemo.Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, WPARAM(-1), LPARAM(0));
```

btw, the delphi NativeUint definition for the WPARAM type is correct, because is a unsigned 32-bit on x86 and unsigned 64-bit on x64.